# SPGridView and dynamic columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, splist, spgridview

I would like to display part of a Sharepoint List in a Visual Web Part. I read about SPGridView but how can i make the number of columns dynamic (i don't know how long my list will be beforehand), and how can I create columns in columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Using c# Api, you can find out what are the columns :

Example using :

```
SPList list = web.List["My list"];
list.Fields...
```

And create the SPGridView Column dynamically by c# Code as well

```
GridView listTypeBot = new GridView();

// Create my column
BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.HeaderText = "Types of bot available";

// Add my column to my gridview
listTypeBot.Columns.Add(bf);
```

Code provided as example (not working code)